# Chrome does not show exit full screen window when moving mouse to top of screen

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

So I was testing my site for full screen mode and I noticed that when you move your mouse to the top of your screen when in full screen mode it doesn't show the little window that allowed you to exit full screen without hitting F11. Is this a bug or is it intentionally removed from the latest chrome update? It's pretty annoying.

PS: I did recently reinstall my pc and since then I noticed some changes I am not very happy about :(

Answer (score 0):

Intentional change. And yes it's really annoying, especially if you don't have F11 key :-(

Fix being discussed here:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=594868